# Using same name for attribute and getter

Tags: python, flask, getter-setter

I have following class/model:

```py
class Recipe(db.Model):
    ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(("users.id")), nullable=False, index=True)
    author = db.relationship("User", uselist=False, back_populates="diets")
    ...

    # Permissions
    def can_view(self, user = None) -> bool:
        if user is None:
            user = current_user
        return self.author == user
```

I can use `recipe.can_view()` or `recipe.can_view(some_user)`, but I want to be able to call `recipe.can_view` instead of `recipe.can_view()`, and I don't know what's a nice solution for that.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraind you cannot have one name and expect Python to read your mind. If you can do `recipe.can_view(user)`, then `can_view` is a callable. It cannot be a bool at the same time. (creating a callable bool would be possible, but don't go that way)

Comment: So I need to have separately named attribute? Oh, shame. But I see how what I want could make some problems. Thanks!

Comment: I would go with `can_view(user)` and optionally `can_current_user_view`...

Comment: Makes sense, nice and explicit (only bit long). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I cannot do that (at least without making some mess).

So, I went with the solution proposed by @zvone in comments:

> I would go with `can_view(user)` and `can_current_user_view`

So, my code is:

```py
    def can_view(self, user) -> bool:
        return self.is_author(user) or user.is_admin or self.is_public

    @property
    def can_current_user_view(self) -> bool:
        return self.can_view(user=current_user)
```